# Cannot set TextView's gravity in constraint layout

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-constraintlayout, gravity

I am programmatically adding TextView to ConstrainLayout. Positioning works fine, but I cannot set text's gravity to left. It's centered between guidelines.

```
conLayout.addView(myTextView);
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(conLayout);
constraintSet.connect(myTextView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, divider.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM);
constraintSet.connect(myTextView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, R.id.guideline1, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
constraintSet.connect(myTextView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, R.id.guideline2, ConstraintSet.LEFT);
constraintSet.constrainDefaultHeight(myTextView.getId(), ConstraintSet.WRAP_CONTENT);
constraintSet.applyTo(conLayout);
myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

When I do all the above in XML, gravity is working, but I need to add this textview programmatically.

Comment: Could you post also your layout XML?

Answer (score 0):

```
myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
```

If I recall correctly: It sets "inner gravity" aka text gravity within TextView. If that's what you want - make sure to set LayoutParams of your desired size. (Default is WrapContent on both, width and height)

Answer (score 0):

try to use this

```
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
    myTextView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating "dummy" textview with gravity:left attribute, and setting LayoutParams of actual TextView to dummy.getLayoutParams().